# WrapGrid Bug in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, grid, windows-store-apps

I tried to initialize `WrapGrid` in my application and I set its `height` and `width` and `itemheight` and `itemwidth` then i added childrens to it as a `Border` control
Then i added this `WrapGrid` as a child in `Canvas` the same like normal windows 7 application but i got `xaml` bug where is the problem !!!!?

```
 WrapGrid new_wrap = new WrapGrid();
            new_wrap.Height = 75;
            new_wrap.Width = 75;
            new_wrap.ItemHeight = 16;
            new_wrap.ItemWidth = 16;
 Border imgborder = new Border();
                imgborder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5);
                imgborder.Height = 16;
                imgborder.Width = 16;
                imgborder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                imgborder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                imgborder.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
                new_wrap.Children.Add(imgborder);
new_shape_g.Children.Add(new_wrap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way is to use  `VariableSizedWrapGrid` instead of `WrapGrid` and it will work.